# HAProxy - option forward for except a white-list of networks

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I would like to use the haproxy `option forwardfor except network-here` for multiple networks, not just a single one.

I'm looking for something like

```
option forwardfor except 'multiple networks here'
```

I tried a few things that did not work like appending the ips in a single `forwardfor` command like shown below which resulted in a syntax error:

```
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8 , 1.1.1.1/32, 2.2.2.2/32
```

I also tried specifying multiple `forwardfor` commands in a row, one for each network like show below. This also did not work as each `forwardfor` command overwrote the previous one which resulted in only the last `forwardfor` command to be counted and not the rest which is not what I am looking for.

```
frontend  main
    bind         my-ip-here:5356-60000
    mode                 http
    option               http_proxy
    option forwardfor    except 127.0.0.0/8 #local network
    option forwardfor    except 1.2.3.4/32 #example ip 1
    option forwardfor    except 5.6.7.8 #example ip 2
    option forwardfor    except 9.10.11.12/32 #example ip 3
    maxconn              950
    timeout              client  30s
    default_backend      mybackendserver
```

How can I `forwardfor except` multiple networks in haproxy?

Comment: maybe you can try `option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8 except 1.2.3.4/32 except 5.6.7.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a somewhat hacky solution, it was not my first choice but it works for my needs. In the haproxy config I am using an acl whitelist that contains all the ips that I do not wish to forwardfor. If the request comes from an ip that exists in the whitelist, haproxy will use a second backend that is identical to the first one, except that it does not forwardfor. I basically moved the forwardfor option to the backend portion instead of the frontend.

so,

```
    frontend  main
        bind         myip:5356-60000
        mode                 http
        option               http_proxy
        maxconn              950
        timeout              client  30s
        acl white_list_noforward src 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 etc..
        #explanation: if the ip is not found in the whitelist, use the backend_that_forwards, else, and the ip is in the whitelist use the backend_that_DOESNT_forward 
        use_backend backend_that_forwards if !white_list_noforward
        use_backend backend_that_DOESNT_forward if white_list_noforward  
        #default to the backend that forwards just in case something goes wrong
        default_backend      use_backend backend_that_forwards

   backend_that_forwards #forwards client ip
        mode        http
        option forwardfor    except 127.0.0.0/8 # <-- THIS forwards the real client ip except 127.0.0.0/8
        balance     roundrobin
        timeout     connect 5s
        timeout     server  5s
        server      static 127.0.0.1:80 # same server for both backends

  backend_that_DOESNT_forward #DOES NOT forward the client-ip (No option forwardfor is used here), used to handle all requests coming in from ips that I do not wish to forward for
       mode        http
       balance     roundrobin
       timeout     connect 5s
       timeout     server  5s
       server      static 127.0.0.1:80 # same server for both backends
```